# Read all textual data from json into html using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsonp

I want to use json file as a placeholder for all textual data that exists in my html file. I'm trying to load all that data through js. I wrote a method that takes the id of element and in return it changes the innerHTML to value from json.

I know that i cant use onload method, because onload works only on specific tags and I found that i can call that method right after that tag just using script tag, but it does not read the data in html.

P.S. May be someone has a better idea of how to load that data from json, because my method does not seam very good

this is my html file + the js method

```
<body>
    <p id="test"> </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">myFunction(this.id);</script>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function  myFunction(id){

               $.ajax({
                   url:'data.json',
                   dataType:'json',
                   type:'get',
                   cache:false,
                   success:function(data){
                    $(data.articles).each(function(index, value){
                        console.log(value.name);
                        id.innerHTML=value.name;
                        })
                    }
                });
            }
    </script>
</body>
```

and this is my json file

```
{
"articles":[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name" :"name11"
    }
]}
```

Comment: use `$( document ).ready(function() {});` function

Comment: No need for that @SanchitPatiyal as her `script` tag is loaded after the DOM she wants to populate

Comment: @3Dos yeah i see my bad\

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">myFunction(this.id);</script> this.id is wrong. You may pass document.getElementById('test')

Comment: Why using 2 separate tags for defining the function and calling it ? you could call it right after defining it

Comment: wts the error coming

Comment: @3Dos I'm using 2 seperate tags because I want to call that method multiple times and kind of don't want to write the same method over and over again

Comment: Irfan TahirKheli-  I tried that, but it does not load the value anyways

Comment: @Aina You can do so without calling the method in separate tags. I don't see the problem

Comment: `url:'data.json'` - this is weird. You are trying to send request giving an adress to a file. Do you have any error logs in console ? like Cross-origin... My question is, do you use some server to test it ?

Comment: ok, I solved the problem. :D I moved the script tag that contains the actual method at the beginning of body and now it loads the value. But still if anyone as a better idea of how to load json data into html feel free to tell

Comment: hodiecode the console was clear with no errors, and no I dont have any server to test it. I just have a json file on my directory

Comment: @Aina of course code that you provided should not work. You have first call myFunction() and after that u declareted it.

Comment: but... What is more interesting why it works locally for u, because i got this error
`Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

so I assume url needs to lead to http...  `url:'http://localhost:3000/data.json'`